# How to modify the write concern levels?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection with 100,000,000 documents, of which I am performing updates each minute. Something like this:

```
var writeOptions = new BulkWriteOptions { IsOrdered = false };

// Applying several operations within the one request.
operationList.Add(new UpdateOneModel<JobInfoRecord>(Builders<JobInfoRecord>.Filter.Eq("_id", document.JobId),
                                 Builders<JobInfoRecord>.Update.Set("JobInfo", newInfo)));

await jobInfoDocuments.BulkWriteAsync(operationList, writeOptions);
```

How can I change the write concern level from 1 (as default) to 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`WithWriteConcern`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_WithWriteConcern.htm) method on your MongoCollection object to get a new IMongoCollection object which will be queried with the provided write concern.

```
 var jobInfoDocumentsCareless = jobInfoDocuments.WithWriteConcern(WriteConcern.Unacknowledged);
 await jobInfoDocumentsCareless.BulkWriteAsync(operationList, writeOptions);
```

Comment: `WriteConcern.Unacknowledged` its a 0 concern level? Which one is default `WriteConcern.Acknowledged`?

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko WriteConcern.Unacknowledged is equivalent to `{ w:0 }`. Acknowledged means, according to [the documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html), "wait for acknowledgement, using the default write concern configured on the server". So it depends on the mongod configuration. If you want to be sure, you can also use [the WriteConcern constructors](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html#WriteConcern-int-) to instantiate your own WriteConcern object with custom settings for w, journal, fsync and timeout.

Comment: So if I want to speed up the process of update I need to use `{ w:0 }` Am I right?

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko When you are willing to take the risk which comes from completely ignoring any possible errors which might occur, then yes.